# Replicacion MONGOCLIENTDB: ServerSelectionTimeoutError

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

tengo un error al tratar de replicar 3 bases de datos, las maquinas replican si configuro una de manera manual, ahora al querer realizarlo para cuando cualquiera de las 3 se pueda caer la otra pase a primary, no puedo tengo error adjunto al titulo

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    # 'MONGO_URI': 'mongodb://facci:facci@server-quito,server-manta,server-guayaquil:27017/?replicaSet=rsfacc'
    'db': 'dbprueba',
    'host': '192.168.100.57',
    'replicaSet': 'rsfacc',
    'read_preference' :ReadPreference.PRIMARY,
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'admin',
    'port': 27017   
}
#**** O ****
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] =[ {
    'db': 'dbprueba',
    'host': '192.168.100.57',
    'replicaSet': 'rsfacc',
    'read_preference' :ReadPreference.PRIMARY,
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'admin',
    'port': 27017   
},
{
    'db': 'dbprueba',
    'host': '192.168.100.56',
    'replicaSet': 'rsfacc',
    'read_preference' :ReadPreference.SECONDARY,
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'admin',
    'port': 27017   
}
]
```

Comment: ¿Ese es todo el error que te marca?

Comment: pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: server-manta:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known,server-quito:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known,server-guayaquil:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61705fb75e812302132ef9bc, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('server-guayaquil', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('server-guayaquil:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')>, <ServerDescriptio